# How to compare Scala Twitter Futures?

Tags: scala, future, twitter-util

I'm working on a backend migration on some scala code. The code current returns com.twitter.util.Future[A] and I am taking the response from my new backend and transforming it into Future[A] as well

To monitor the migration, I want to do a comparison so I can tell how often the response from the 2 backends differ, so I have something like

```
val b1Resp: Future[A] = getResponseFromBackend1()
val b2Resp: Future[A] = getResponseFromBackend2() map { resp => convert(resp)}

return b1Resp
```

I want to verify that the results of the futures are either the same or that they both fail.  On discrepancies, I will be publishing a metric.

Moreover, I don't want to delay the return. I don't really care when the metric is published (within reason of course), so it's okay to allow execution to continue

How do I do the comparison?

Comment: I want to make sure that I understood correctly, so you want to make sure that the results are the same, and you want to also benchmark the two methods and compare them?

Comment: I don't need to benchmark. I just want to make sure the results are the same, including if they fail. I don't want to delay the return (eg, I don't want to wait for the futures to complete in this method) as it will impact the overall performance

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Twitter `Future`s but looking at the documentation you can: use 
`map` and `handle` methods to wrap the result in a `Try` (effectively getting `Future[Try[A]]` for each response), then use a for comprehension to combine the results into a tuple (`Future[(Try[A], Try[A])]`) and finally use `addEventListener` to execute a callback recording the metric when the result `Future` completes.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I think that will work. It looks like Twitter's Future even has a built in liftToTry method to help with this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The broad outline of what you want to do is

```scala
{
  val b1Resp: Future[A] = getResponseFromBackend1()
  val b2Resp: Future[A] = getResponseFromBackend2() map { resp => convert(resp)}

  Future.join(b1Resp, b2Resp)  // combine the two futures into a future of a pair of their values
    .foreach {                 // when both are complete...
      case (b1, b2) =>
        // compare and tickle a metric or whatever
        ()  // explicit Unit value, in case the compiler warns about discarding a value
    }

  b1Resp  // return should generally be avoided in Scala
}
```

Note that `Future.join.foreach` just arranges for the comparison etc. to happen in the future; it should only add a few microseconds to the block.

For standard library futures, the equivalent to `Future.join.foreach` is (assuming an implicit `ExecutionContext` is in scope):

```scala
b1Resp.zip(b2Resp)
  .foreach {
    // as above
  }
```

Comment: Worth noting that in both of these, the comparison will only happen if both futures succeed.  One option for comparing failures would be to have a nested `rescue` (Twitter) or `recoverWith` (standard library) between the `join`/`zip` and the `foreach`, though this would mean that the `foreach` would now see an `(Any, Any)`.